# What's the meaning of "trip over"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Below is a passage from [this](http://www.salon.com/2011/11/20/diary_of_a_porn_store_clerk/) article:

> The next day I **trip over** the writer’s wet dream and worst nightmare, the content farm. After some quick math, I figure that five pages of “How to Ride a Bicycle in Ankara” and “Grinding Coffee Beans for Small Business Owners” would pay as much as a day at the booths. It doesn’t take much to convince me to quit.

What does *trip over* mean mentioned above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context, "trip over" means "find by accident", much in the way that if you didn't see that exposed tree root on the ground, your foot would find it accidentally, and you would trip over it.

Comment: other synonyms would be "discover" or "happen upon"

Answer (score 0):

I think of it as finding something surprising that I hadn't realized was right in front of me.